# Dynamic "Changing Cell to" in Goal Seek

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table like below.
[image: Table Image]

I want to perform a goal seek analysis on cell `E5` to 0 by changing the corresponding Var2 of minimum amongst Var1.

So in this image, the minimum of Var1 is 19. Its corresponding Var2 value is `B3`. Hence I'd do a goal seek to set cell `E5` to 0 by changing cell `B3`.

To make it more clear, I am looking something like this

Set Cell = `E5`

To Value =0

By Changing Cell to `=CELL("address",INDEX(B3:B7,MATCH(MIN(A3:A7),A3:A7,0)))`

Please provide a solution for this or some direction to approach such problems.

Comment: Word of advice: presumably you're being downvoted for asking for help without showing working.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander I've shown my work in the question. I was trying to use `CELL("address",INDEX(B3:B7,MATCH(MIN(A3:A7),A3:A7,0)))` for the changing cell value in Goal Seek

Comment: Did my suggestion help?

Answer (score 0):

No need for VBA. It can be done using a formula in the goal seek box.

[image]

Assuming your example, I used:

```
=INDIRECT("B"&(MATCH(MIN(A2:A6),A2:A6,0))+1)
```

(The MIN formula finds the minimum value in the range, MATCH finds its position in the range, we then take B and this value + 1 (because of the headers) to get the corresponding value in B, and then INDIRECT tells Excel to read it as an address.)

Excel 2010 accepted this (though it didn't find an answer, given your parameters...)